# Flash Fill in Excel result in columns - and not in rows

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I want Flash Fill results in columns.

Data is like this:

[image]

Could VBA help here?
The VBA could transpose the data in one row, Flash Fill that array, and then transpose it back in the next row.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking,... we know what Transpose and Autofill is, but what is your expected outcome or result?

Comment: If the data (IN00-DL, IN03-CL ...) were in a column, I could have written the first value I want (IN00) and press Ctrl + E for Flash Fill.
But since data is a row, I cannot use Flash Fill.

In its current form - where the first row has the entire data, if I write IN03-CL as the Flash Fill input, I cannot press Flash Fill.

My expected result is that IN03, IN04, IN06 comes in first row.
DL, CL, KL ... comes in the second row.

These results should come using Flash Fill though - so that I can extract data even if my input changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is dynamic by length of header and string splits by `-`

```
Option Explicit

Sub FlashFill()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim MyCell As Range, StringRange As Range, Arr, i, lcol

Set StringRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

For Each MyCell In StringRange
    Arr = Split(MyCell, "-")
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            MyCell.Offset(i + 1) = Arr(i)
        Next i
    Arr = ""
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

---

Resulting in the lyrics of the worst song ever written output looking like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this would only work with this specific data structure.
I am looking for a Flash Fill that can give me the same results.

Comment: add a better example with input & output to your question